# Search for multiple instances of a substring within a string in Python 3.4 without using find()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a program that searches for all instances of a substring within a given string and then adds the index of each substring found to a list.

```
dna = input("Input a DNA string: ")
substring = input("Input a substring to search for in DNA: ")

def find_all(substring, dna):
    index_list = []
    index = 0 - len(dna)
    try:
        while True:
            index = dna.index(substring, index + len(dna))
            index_list.append(index)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return index_list

print(find_all(substring, dna))
```

If I input

```
Input a DNA string: GATACAGATACA
Input a substring to search for in DNA: ATA
[1]
```

It prints the first index at which it is found, but it stops there. How do I get it to print every index at which it is found?

Comment: Why can't you use `.find`?  That seems an odd requirement . . .

Comment: I fixed your code indentation, as it doesn't seem like that is the issue. You might want to make sure that it is now as you have it.

Comment: @mgilson I agree. I could imagine either not being able to use any string methods for learning purposes, or having access to all of them. But having access to `str.index` but not `str.find` seems strange.

Comment: Seems like a school assignment to disallow a use of .find() Is regex use allowed?

Comment: It specifically says that I should not use the find() function, and that I should come up with a method of doing it without it. I think it's maybe to get us to understand how find() works.

Comment: It's a beginning python course, and I have very little experience. It needs to be a simple program that reproduces the find() function without actually utilizing it. I need to be able to explain how it works to the grader, so think of this from the perspective of someone who just started learning Python a month ago.

Comment: If you can use everything except of `find` then use `re.finditer` and get the index from the resulting match objects: `[match.start() for match in re.finditer('({})'.format(substring), dna)]`.

Comment: I'm guessing if they don't want you to use `str.find` they really don't want you to use `str.index` either, and they're expecting you to do it by iterating character by character.

Comment: But if you want to screw with your professor, I'd validate that both strings are ASCII, then `ctypes` up `strstr`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could find all substrings and use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) to find the `index` of each that matches the required `substring`:

```
def find_all(substring, dna):
    subs = [dna[i:i+len(substring)] for i in range(0,len(dna))]
    return [ind for ind, ele in enumerate(subs) if ele == substring]

In [9]: dna = "GATACAGATACA"

In [10]: substring = "ATA"

In [11]: (find_all(substring, dna))
Out[11]: [1, 7]
```

subs using the above inputs looks like:

```
['GAT', 'ATA', 'TAC', 'ACA', 'CAG', 'AGA', 'GAT', 'ATA', 'TAC', 'ACA', 'CA', 'A']
```

It finds all possible substrings of the len of the substring we are looking for.

Then  `[ind for ind, ele in enumerate(subs) if ele == substring]` gets the `ind/index` of each element `if ele == substring`,  if the `ele/substring` matches our required `substring`.

As abarnet suggested in the comments, it would be better to make `subs` a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to avoid building a list unnecessarily:

```
def find_all(substring, dna):
    # now  a generator expression 
    subs = (dna[i:i+len(substring)] for i in range(0,len(dna)))
    return [ind for ind, ele in enumerate(subs) if ele == substring]
```

Comment: You might want to change `subs` to a generator expression, because you don't really need to waste memory building all the substrings at once here… but on the other hand, this version may be easier to understand while stepping through in the debugger, which could certainly be useful to the asker.

Comment: @abarnert, originally I had it all in one line with subs as a gen exp but just to make it easier to follow and  what is in subs I changed it to two lines and and made subs a list, I will add a version with a gen exp too I think

Answer (score 0):

### Example with REGEX

```
>>> import re
>>> p =re.compile( "ATA" )
>>> p.findall( "GATACAGATACA" )
['ATA', 'ATA']
```

Check details about other REGEX service to tailor it to your needs.

In case you need also {CATG}-SubSequence-fragment position in a DNA-string, try:

```
>>> DNA = "GATACAGATACA"
>>> Seq = "ATA"
>>> for SeqFOUND in re.finditer( Seq, DNA ):
...     print "%02d-%02d: %s " % ( SeqFOUND.start(), SeqFOUND.end(), SeqFOUND.group(0) )
...
01-04: ATA
07-10: ATA
>>>
```

Comment: How would you tailor `findall` to give you the index of the substrings? `findall` returns just a list of strings.

Comment: That's better (and nearly as beautiful as the version I wrote in the comments some minutes before your answer) :-)

Comment: @Matthias Yes, a MATRIX reload needed :)   [show 4 more comments] have shown me your ( almost a nose-length more beautiful piece )

Comment: @Matthias upon re-reading your one, an ultimate one-liner py-extremist would put `[match.start() for match in re.finditer('({})'.format(input("Input a substring to search for in DNA: ")), input("Input a DNA string: "))]` wouldn't she/he?